# Send Command Not Working When A Program Gets Run In AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

i have some code which will if the user types something, it will type that to notepad, but it is only opening notepad and not typing.

```
InputBox, UserInput, NoteType, Enter something to type in notepad., , 640, 480
if ErrorLevel
    ExitApp
else
    Run, Notepad
    Send, %UserInput%
```

Does anyone seem to have a solution for this?

Comment: Do use WinWait, WinActivate and WinWaitActive after the Run and before the Send command.

Comment: @user3419297 So like, 
InputBox, UserInput, NoteType, Enter What You Want To Type., , 640, 480
if ErrorLevel
    ExitApp
else
    Run Notepad
    WinWait, Untitled - Notepad, WinText, 1 [, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
    WinActivate, [ Untitled - Notepad, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
    WinWaitActive, [ Untitled - Notepad, 1, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
    Send %UserInput%

Comment: @user3419297 It does not work tho

Comment: Omit parameters in the commands if you don't have any values for them: `WinWait, Untitled - Notepad` etc.

Comment: @user3419297 Thanks alot! Don't know how to flag as correct but your the best.

Answer (score 0):

There is a caveat when using if…else blocks in AHK, when executing multiple lines of code you have to use curly braces to enclose the block. Otherwise it just executes the first line in the block. Example:

```
InputBox, UserInput, NoteType, Enter something to type in notepad., , 640, 480
if ErrorLevel {
    ExitApp
} else {
    Run, Notepad
    Send, %UserInput%
}
```

That should work now.